# How to use Google Analytics API as a Web Application without userinteraction for Login Screen and Allow Access Prompt?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a server-side application to pull data from my Google Analytics account using PHP. I have registered my application in a Google API Console as a Web Application. I want to run this application using Terminal/Command Prompt. To run this application on a Terminal/Command Prompt I want to get rid of Login Screen and Allow Access prompt.

Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to get rid of Login Screen and Allow Access Prompt. I have changed `approval_prompt` to `auto` but I am still getting Allow Access Prompt for the new session.

What are the required changes to run this application without user interaction for Login Screen and Allow Access Prompt?

Comment: Hi @siddharth, This is a real life question that most programmers run into, I'm running into it now, I want to ask you if you figure out any solution for it, I read somewhere that you should save the access token and the refresh token as a variable and feed it to SetAcess() function, but I didn't get it to work. please let me know if you figure out anything, that will be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried YQL Tables for Google Analytics?

https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/google/google.analytics.xml